# How to get the firebase storage path from the the storage url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to write a migration script to copy the storage urls stored in firestore from the development project to the staging and production projects.

I'm querying all documents in Firestore, filtering the documents that contain one of the two strings:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${BUCKET_ID}/o/{FILEPATH}
```

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/${BUCKET_ID}/{FILEPATH}
```

I noticed the first is used when the image was uploaded from the javascript client and the second when it was uploaded from Cloud Functions.

Is there an easy to get the storage path from the urls without parsing them?
Is there an easier way to achieve migrating storage urls to a new project?

*Note: I want to get the storage path from the url. I know the other way around is straightforward.*

Comment: To be clear, you want to obtain the "{FILEPATH}" part from the storage url that you are retrieving or are you just looking for a simpler way to retrieve the storage url ?

Comment: @Mayeru I have the url stored in Firestore and I want to get the {FILEPATH} out of it.

Answer (score 2):

I have %2F as the URL delimiter. My solution to build the path:

```
var pictureItem = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<your project>/o/images%2FREOXjfQrYmXFSKFVItoQqnzSCYs1%2F717752.jpg?alt=media&token=1cff5b5c-8d10-40d8-8fd1-98720983c44b"
var url_token = pictureItem.split('?');
var url = url_token[0].split('/');
var filePath = url[url.length - 1].replaceAll("%2F", "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the "{FILEPATH}" part from the urls you have stored, this is the javascript code that I would suggest to achieve this:

```js
  var data = ['https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my_bucket_id/o/file_path1','https://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket_id/file_path2','https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my_bucket_id/o/file_path3','https://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket_id/file_path4','https://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket_id/file_path5','https://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket_id/file_path6','https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my_bucket_id/o/file_path7']; //sample data
  
  var treated_data = [];
  
  for (url of data) {
    var list = url.split('/'); // split the url by /
    treated_data.push(list[list.length - 1]); // grabbing and saving the last part.
  }
  
  console.log(treated_data); // here you have all your FILEPATH part
```

Notes:

- Modify the code according to the actual structure that you use to handle the data.
- Since the FILEPATH part is at the end of the urls you are retrieving it doesn't matter which url you are treating, you will only get the last part.
- If this doesn't help you please give more information on your question (how is your migration process, which script are you using to handle the migration...)

Answer (score 0):

You can import and use `getDownloadURL` from 'firebase/storage'

usage :

```js
getDownloadURL(storageRef).then( url => {
    ...
});
```

Comment: The question is about obtaining the path once you already have the URL. Your answer is useful if you need the other way around.