# How can I safely delete a video from Firebase storage with React Native Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I have a react native chat application where users can send messages to other users. A simplified message object looks like this:

```
interface Message {
  senderId: string,
  text: string,
  videoDownloadUrl: string
}
```

The message is stored in a `messages` collection in [firestore](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage) and the according video is stored in [storage](https://rnfirebase.io/storage/usage). In the message object I only store the `downloadUrl` of the video and not the actual url, where the video is located on the firabase storage server. How Can I safely delete such a message and its video without letting the user know the actual path to the video?

My thoughts are that it would be a security issue if the user had access to the actual path of the video. So I just put the downloadUrl in the message object. Is this thought correct or can I just give the user access to the actual path? I don't see any way how to delete a message's video without the path to the video.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different questions in your post.  The first question has already been asked several times.  The path to the object is stored within the download URL itself.

- [How to get the firebase storage path from the the storage url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56762486/how-to-get-the-firebase-storage-path-from-the-the-storage-url)
- [Get Firebase storage Ref path from download url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492852/get-firebase-storage-ref-path-from-download-url)

For your second question:

There is no inherent problem with providing a path to an object in Cloud Storage.  The path is encoded into the download URL anyway, so it's not really a secret since you are already giving up the download URL to the user.  What you should do is provide [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security) for your storage bucket that restrict downloads according to your security requirements.  These requirements should be related to the user's account in Firebase Authentication to determine who should be able to read or write which objects.

Security rules don't apply to download URLs, just direct downloads using the Firebase SDKs.